# sccm 1702 sql server service running account

Tags: sql, sccm

I am having an issue with the installation of SCCM 1702. When it runs it's pre-requisite check I get an error indicating the login account of the sql server is incorrect. It is specifically referencing the sql on the SCCM server setup during the ADK installation. I have updated as per it's instructions (see screen shot) but I continue to get the error. Has anyone else run into this? I have seen several questions posted about this online, but no answers.

[SCCM prereq error & sql manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU1tg.png)

Comment: First, check the SQL Server version you have installed : SQL Express is not supported. Second, the error message is quite clear : you have to start the MSSQL Windows Service using a domain account or Local System or Network Service : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36617.sccm-2016-troubleshooting-resolve-sql-server-service-account-issue-during-setup.aspx

Comment: This turned out to be there was an additional instance of SQL on the local host. Even though I was specifying during the steps to use the 2016 sql server, it was still picking up an instance locally and puking because of that.

Answer (score 0):

There was an instance of sql express on the same host as SCCM. Even though in the setup prompts I told it to use the SQL on the 2016 server, it still did not like that express was installed locally. Once I removed it, it went right through.